# Как найти минимум и максимум вручную Javascript. почему код работает неверно

Tags: javascript, max, min

Нужно по строке "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6" вывести строку, содержащую максимум и минимум.
Почему код выводит  '6 -214' вместо '542 -214'?
Код:

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  let arr = numbers.split(" ");
  let min = arr[0];
  let max = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
    if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
  }
  return `${max} ${min}`;
}
console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Вы сравниваете строки.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  let arr = numbers.split(" ").map(Number);
  let min = arr[0];
  let max = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
    if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
  }
  return `${max} ${min}`;
}
console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!